# Error occurring in localhost but not on my website even though the code is the same - how?

Tags: node.js, git, twitter-bootstrap, express

I am getting an error on a form submit in localhost, but no errors on my live website.

The error is: `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

I ran `git diff` to see the differences between my remote and local repos, and there were some since I had made a couple of changes. Those changes were: adding a custom bootstrap configuration (I wanted to change the base font from 14 to 18px) and uninstalling New Relic, an npm package for analytics. I am not sure how any of that would have caused the error, I am just trying to explain thoroughly.

My remote git repository is the code behind my live site, which is not getting this error, so I decided to make my local files match my remote, so I ran:

`git fetch origin`

`git reset --hard origin/master`

`git clean -f`

and then ran `git diff` again and there were no differences this time. That is what is puzzling to me. It seems like there should be no difference. Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: The error you're getting means that you've already responded to the initial request. Validate that you are responding twice in the code that handles your form submit. There are a couple ways to fix this, however, without any code there's no way to really help you.

Comment: This is a wild guess, but one possible cause of this is a difference in the serving environment. For instance, if on localhost you are running just the server directly, but on the web site, there is something in front of it, like an Nginx proxy, the thing in front may be sending headers.

Answer (score 0):

As a result of some earlier testing I had created duplicate usernames, and this error is only occurring when logged in with one of the duplicates, which only exist in my local DB. That explains why I was getting this error in localhost and not in my live site.